# Addition using recursion printing garbage

Tags: c++, recursion

I have this very small piece of code. But it is giving me garbage values instead of a proper answer. Working on mvs 2010. The program does not also terminate normally.

```
 long  sumsq_diff (int arr1[],int size1, int arr2[],int size2, int i)
{
    if(i < size2)
    {
        return ( (arr1[i]-arr2[i]) * (arr1[i]-arr2[i]) ) + 
                sumsq_diff (arr1,size1,arr2,size2, i + 1) ;
    }
    else 
        return 0 ;
}


int main ()
{
     const int size1 = 5 ;
     const int size2 = 5 ;
     int arr1 [size1] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} ;
     int arr2 [size2] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} ;
     int ans =  sumsq_diff (arr1,size1,arr2, size2, 0) ;
     cout << ans ;
     return 0 ;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Outputs "55" for me and passes all validity tests.

Comment: I have tried it on two different pc's.
But still the same problem. The code it seems is fine otherwise.

Comment: Most likely either the code you're compiling is different from the code you pasted (other than the missing include file) or something is wrong with the platform you are compiling on.

Comment: The code is same, and i have tried code blocks too.

Comment: Works for me as well. Are you running "managed" C++ or an oddball Microsoft variation like that?

Comment: And what are the garbage value and proper value?

Comment: @Dynguss I Beg your pardon. I am a beginner. Not familiar with what you said.

Comment: Works for me too. What result do you get, exactly? What do you mean by "does not terminate normally"? Be very specific.

Comment: No problem, Sasha, I went ahead and ran it as CLR C++ and it works fine also.

Comment: its somewhat -800324...
BY Improper termination i mean, when i debug it, it executes the program again after main.

Comment: This is obviously not the code in its entirety. It is missing an include and a using namespace. Please, post the contents of the whole file.

Comment: Are the arrays you give to this `sumsq_diff` function the same you have in this post?

Comment: It seems to be an issue with your system, I wonder what happens if you change `long` to `int` for the return type of `sumsq_diff`?

Comment: Two things jump out at me - firstly, you are not checking if i < size1, which could cause issues if you use this code generally.  Secondly, you might want to check the size of your stack.

Comment: Issue got resolved when i changed the condition to `i == size2`. Dont know why it was so